# CORS issue in Node/Express if we remove www prefix

Tags: node.js, express, cors

We have a NodeJS/Express server that loads an HTML5 game we have stored on service outside of our server (think Amazon S3). The game must talk to our stats backend still on our NodeJS/Express server, but since it's on a different domain from the game that's running we encountered CORS issues.  We fixed this by using the Node cors module and doing this with our route:

`router.put("/stats/", cors(), async (req, res) => {`
...

All has been fine, but we just learned if you visit our website WITHOUT the www prefix it still gives a CORS issue.  As in if you visit us at www.example.com everything works, the game loads, and it can report stats back.  But if you visit us at example.com then the game still loads, but it's giving this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.example.com/api/stats/' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

From what I understand, how we're using the cors package it should enable all cors requests on that route.  So why is it blocking this one?

Answer (score 0):

Well no one ever responded, but we've managed to solve this just by using a 301 hostname redirect.  Still not sure why CORS isn't working, but this fixes our specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [cors lib from nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).
You can make a configuration for cors to support both domains.

As an example:

```
const cors = require('cors')
//cors config
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['https://example.com', 'https://www.example.com']
  methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
  optionsSuccessStatus:200,
  credentials: true
}))
```

Comment: We do use that lib.  However we don't use a specific configuration, which the docuentation says will default to this: 
{
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "preflightContinue": false,
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
}

Origin of * should be enough to prevent our error but it doesn't.